# Maximum file size in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm community edition 2016, and I notice that I can't open large data input files or logs (20MB). The editor simply says "File XXX is to large (SIZE)".

And not only that, but there seems to be no way of changing the limit. The official documentation mentions a way to increase the maximum size for using intellisense, but not for the maximum size of files that can be opened at all. Can that be true? Is this really an IDE that cannot open large logs *in any way at all*?

Answer (score 9):

For Pycharm 2018, you can go **Help-> edit custom properties**

then add this line

```
idea.max.content.load.filesize=25000
```

And then **restart** pycharm.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make a `idea.properties` file in one of the following locations.

- For Windows: in %USERPROFILE%.PyCharm XX
- For *NIX: in ~/.PyCharm XX
- For Mac OS X: in ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm XX

In that file you will need to add one line to specify the max file size in kilobytes:

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=25000
```

Other properties that can be altered can be found at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/file-idea-properties.html

Comment: I just saw that you have already seen the way to alter the maximum file size for intellisense but it seems to be just the maximum file size period for PyCharm. I just opened a 30MB log file after changing the max file size for intellisense.

Comment: For newer versions of Pycharm, the `idea.properties` file should be located in ~/.PyCharm XX/config in *NIX

Answer (score 4):

Change Filelimit Pycharm for **Mac OS**:

- You need to go to the Programs folder
- Click on the *show package contents* on Pycharm-icon to open PyCharm application contents
- You need to go to *Contents/bi*n and open **idea.properties** file
- Now, change the value of *idea.max.intellisense.filesize* from 2500 to the value that you will be comfortable with. I change mine to 25000.

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=25000
```

- Save the file))) and restart Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

For win10

- For win 10, you could see the file `idea.properties` in

  `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.5\bin`